# Get path from UriBuilder

Tags: java, rest

I am using WebSphere 8.5 with Wink and i need to get the path from a rest client for logging purposes.

When I look at the resource stub in the debugger, i see the UriBuilder with the path set, but I have no getter Method to get the path in String format.

The toString method only delivers org.apache.wink.common.internal.UriBuilderImpl@dd6bce39. So that's not the way.

How can I get the path in string form?
best regards,
m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could call `build()` to have the URI and then to log it.

Comment: Ah I overlooked the build method, because it had varargs as parameters. Thanks ... seems like I need the weekend already.